# How to debug a Java error of "HOME is incorrectly set"?

Tags: hadoop, java-home

```
C:\Users\nilotpal.datta>hdfs namenode -format
Error: JAVA_HOME is incorrectly set.
       Please update C:\hadoop-2.8.0\etc\hadoop\hadoop-env.cmd
'-Dhadoop.security.logger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have attached below my screenshot of environment variables

[image: Environment variables]

Variables from Hadoop:

[image: hadoop-env cmd file]

Answer (score 0):

In C:\hadoop-2.8.0\etc\hadoop\hadoop-env.cmd Set,

```
set JAVA_HOME=your full java path
```

then again format namenode